# What is the error of weighted average?

Tags: statistics, average

I have the following array of numbers:

```
Data = [1.0093723027146584, 1.0046505670796182, 1.0161141384219396, 1.0134308125226419, 0.9968327836577084,
 0.9991179639395691, 1.004309884935752, 1.0045739950900365, 1.0034488516079065, 1.0123691848397993]
```

After calculating the weighted average of these numbers based on the weights:

```
Weights = [0.10402577, 0.07763709, 0.09376677, 0.06940965, 0.05807695,
 0.11757057, 0.13287357, 0.13127618, 0.12285175, 0.0925117 ]
```

I can find the average is $1.00623$.

How to find the error of this weighted average? Should that be the standard deviation of Data? How the weights contribute to the error bar?

Thanks!

Comment: You can work out the weighted standard deviation of the data (square root of the weighted variance, i.e. square root of the weighted average of the squares of the differences from the weighted mean).  The weighted standard error of the weighted mean would be more difficult - how many observations do you have, taking account of the weights?   Those weights sum to $1$ so does that suggest $1$ observation?

Comment: @Henry Thanks for the comment! I normalized the weights to make them sum to 1. I actually did 100 observations.